# Setting HTTPS with Traefik2 on AWS EKS with ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have an AWS EKS cluster with Traefik2 deployed via helm with the following config. The ACM cert set is a wildcard cert *.example.com

```
service:
  enabled: true
  type: LoadBalancer
  annotations: {
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:certificate/"
```

With the following IngressRoute set for the dashboard.

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  namespace: traefik
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik.example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
```

The issue is after pointing the domain in R53 to the Traefik CLB I can only hit the dashboard with HTTP access and not HTTPS. When trying to access via HTTPS I am receiving the "404 page not found" error. The goal is to eventually just have HTTP redirect to HTTPS but unable to hit HTTPS in the first place.

Could there me something in the configuration that I am missing?